# HTML comments in CSS?

Tags: css

I was checking out some of [Amazon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon.com)'s CSS and noticed they have HTML commented out a chunk of CSS. I know there is conditional formatting for Internet Explorer with HTML comments, but I am viewing this in [Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome). What is the purpose of it?

Oh, I should note that these styles are actually being applied.

```
<!-- BeginNav -->

<style type="text/css">

    <!--

    .nav-sprite {
      background-image: url(http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/gno/beacon/BeaconSprite-US-01._V141013396_.png);
    }
    .nav_pop_h {
      background-image: url(http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/gno/beacon/nav-pop-h._V155853593_.png);
    }
    .nav_pop_v {
      background-image: url(http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/gno/beacon/nav-pop-v._V155853593_.png);
    }
    .nav_ie6 .nav_pop_h {
      background-image: url(http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/gno/beacon/nav-pop-8bit-h._V155961234_.png);
    }
    .nav_ie6 .nav_pop_v {
      background-image: url(http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/gno/beacon/nav-pop-8bit-v._V155961234_.png);
    }
    .nav-ajax-loading .nav-ajax-message {
      background: center center url(http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/javascripts/lib/popover/images/snake._V192571611_.gif) no-repeat;
    }
    -->

</style>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's created by someone who thought that visitors of the site use a browser which does not recognise `<style>` tags.

(Ancient) browsers, which do not recognise `<style>` tags, will not show "weird" characters (CSS rules) because of the HTML comments.

Most browsers recognise the `<style>` tag, so the developer seems to use `<!-- -->` out of (bad) habit. It should **not** be used.

Comment: It's better to comment beginning with `<!--/*--><![CDATA/*><!--*/` and ending with `/*<]]>*/ -->`.  This will hide the code from browsers that don't understand it, while still allowing xhtml parers to interpret it, without removing compatibility with browsers that don't understand CDATA.  For the same reason, it is good to comment javascript starting with `<!--//--><![CDATA//><!--` and ending with `// --> <]]>`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's remember that **not only browsers interpret HTML**. **E-mail clients also do this**, and some of them use **old engines or very strange rules**.

Generally, this is **some type of trick which is used when creating a template for HTML e-mails**, so that if the e-mail is opened on the client who does not correctly interpret the `<style>` tag **then the client should not display CSS styles in the body of the message**. And more **modern clients should interpret styles correctly**, because `<! - ->` is not a comment for CSS, but only an incomprehensible syntax that should be ignored by the CSS parser.

In this situation, it can only be legitimatize only if we want to include CSS rules for *Media Queries* in the `<style>` tag. Otherwise, in the e-mail templates when we use ordinary styles, recommended is using the *inline CSS* styles.