# Commenting internal CSS code is not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to comment internal CSS code as shown in the below image, but it's not working for me. If I comment this way, my code is still working on the site.

Is this is the right way to put comments for internal CSS code?

I tried `/* */`, but it didn't work for me.

[image]

Comment: try this // or /* */

Comment: You may already find your answer here: [html comments in css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812489/html-comments-in-css)

Comment: as the software i am using for coding showed comment section in different color, so i thought it will work for css too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `/* */`, not `<!-- -->`.

The second type is HTML, not CSS. The use of HTML comments is a hack having to do with some Microsoft browser and does not work as you might expect it to do.

[Older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812489/html-comments-in-css)

Comment: as the software i am using for coding showed comment section in different color, so i thought it will work for css too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `/* ... */` to comment in CSS:

```
main {
    /* width: 100%; */
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Atleast read the question man..op already said he used this but not working.

Comment: OP already tried that.. read carefully: _i tried `/* */` but didt worked for me_

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure the `/* */` don't work? It is working for me:

```
<html>
<body>
<style>
p { font-size: 2em;}
/*
p { margin:5em;}
*/
p { color: red; }
</style>
<p>Hello World</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not use the answer system as a replacement. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!

Comment: OK, but still this can be accepted as an answer because this is just correct coding.

Comment: @Krant avoid asking questions in your answers, such as _Have you tried?_, _Are you sure?_. If you edit your answer and make it look like a real answer, people may upvote your posts.

Comment: The OP has already said that that commenting style didn't work...why we don't know.